# import and plot time series

Tags: matlab, datetime, import, xls

I want to import date and time as vectors

```
filename='data.xls'; data = readtable(filename); date=data(:,1); 
time=data(:,2); 
date=table2cell(date);time=table2cell(time);time=datenum(time);
```

Then i need to plot date and time against each variable. Can you help me?

[data](https://easyupload.io/7xu5jr)

Comment: Yes sorry, Matlab 2021

Comment: It's unclear to me why you're converting things to cells etc, can't you just do `date=data{:,1}; time=data{:,2}; plot(time,date)`? If not, please include some example data within the question itself, to remove external links. See the advice on creating a  [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that one way is to pick a date like a reference and then make a time vector with the increments of time with respect to the reference.
Example:

```
% Import data
filename='data.xls';
data = readtable(filename);

% Get timestamp vector
d = datetime(strcat(table2array((data(:,1))), {' '}, table2array((data(:,2)))));
deltaTime=[0;seconds(diff(datetime(d,'Format','hh:mm:ss.SSSSSS')))];
time = cumsum(deltaTime);

% Get timeseries for the data
pressure = table2array((data(:,3)));
temperature = timeseries(table2array((data(:,4))), time);
ms = timeseries(table2array((data(:,5))), time);

% Plot
figure(1);
title('Pressure');
hold on;
grid on;
plot(time, pressure, 'b-*');
xlabel('Time [s]');
ylabel('Pressure');
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it but I get the following error:


d = datetime(strcat(table2array((data(:,1))), {' '}, 
                                                      ↑
Error: Invalid expression. When calling a function or indexing a variable, use parentheses. Otherwise, check for mismatched delimiters.

Comment: Ok, when I published, one line of code was splited in two. It was edited, and I think now is correct.

Comment: d = datetime(strcat(table2array((data(:,1))), {' '}, table2array((data(:,2)))));
Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of class 'cell'.

Comment: I´m using Matlab 2019b, and works, maybe in 2021 not but I don´t have avaiable licence to check.

Comment: ok, can i have in x axis the date and time in a format like 01-01-2019 00:00 ?

Comment: Use datetime vector instead of time vector in the plot